# How to make a JavaScript library compatible with multiple promise libraries?

Tags: promise, javascript

I'm writing a library which should be able to produce promises. But I wouldn't want to bind the user of my library to any particular promise implementation. Assuming I won't use any exotic / implementation specific features, are there established best practices for doing this?

For example, is there a minimal compatibility library which detects whether Q, Bluebird, AngularJS promises, ES6 promises... are loaded, and offers me a minimal interface to whichever it may be?

Note: My library needs to *produce promises*, and I'd like to avoid bundling a full promise library inside my own library. (Unless there is a particularly small one, made for this purpose?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this reason - there is the Promises/A+ spec.

[Promises/A+](http://promisesaplus.com/) is a promise *specification* that defines only the `then` method. It describes how different promise libraries interoperate with each other - effectively serving exactly the purpose you describe.

All these libraries you describe - Bluebird, Q and AngularJS's $q are in fact A+ promises and are all run against the test suite.

That minimal interface you describe exists - and it is `then`. Alternatively if you need to create your own promises directly - you may choose any one Promises/A+ library from that list and you are *guaranteed* it will work in all of the other libraries - since they're all Promises/A+ they will assimilate the promises correctly. It will also work between different versions of the library (minus bugs).

If you choose a Promises/A+ library, for example Bluebird in your app - users can use [any conformant implementation](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md).

Here is [the suite](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-tests). If you really want to be able to create promises from scratch - you can ask the users to provide their assimilation method to your library - for example:

```
MyLib.init = function init(assimilator){
    MyLib.assimilator = assimilator
}
MyLib.apiCall = function(){
    // assimilate a returned promise from whatever library you want
    return MyLib.assimilator(promiseYouCreateInWhateverLibrary());
}

MyLib.init(Promise.resolve); // Initialize with Blubird, or native promises
MyLib.init(Q); // Initializes with Q
// initialize with any empty promise with any library
MyLib.init(function(x){ return empty.then(function(x){ return x; });  });
```

Comment: The problem is, this only makes guarantees when I get a promise *passed into* my library, but I need to *produce promises*. Say I bundle Bluebird with my library to produce those promises. Even if my users can easily convert them to, e.g., Q promises in their code, they still need to send Bluebird over the wire to their clients, which is non-trivial. --- I was hoping to find some minimal code to produce promises with whichever promise library happens to be loaded.

Comment: @mhelvens you can ask them for a promise constructor as an argument when initializing your library, or an empty promise you can `then` from. However - the point is that's not necessary since they can interop with Bluebird promises from Q and vice versa seamlessly anyway.

Comment: @mhelvens I've added a more direct answer - but the more important point here is the A+ promise specification. Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Ah, passing the assimilator method is clever! I'm now using a similar initialization scheme, but asking for the 'main library object', then making case distinctions based on the API. But with the assimilator method, I can pretty much go anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: PS: Yes, the Promises/A+ spec part of your answer is definitely the more important point. I just happened to know that already, and I needed that last hint for my particular situation. Good answer overall!

Comment: Well, the alternative is asking for a constructor which is very problematic because it limits you to only use `.then` in your internal library code and since the promise constructor, while well specified is not supported by a lot of libraries yet (although it's getting there - for example Angular 1.3 ships with it).